# Searching a particular cell value in excel using row and column names with python

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

Below is my *code*. I'm trying to capture `rowid` and `columnid` of a particular 'cell' element and that cell value in an excel sheet using row name and column name, but I'm unable to capture it.

```
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    book = open_workbook("D:\A2.xlsx")
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx,cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == "PES":#row value
                   print "Found Row Element"
                   for column in range(sheet.ncols):
                       col = sheet.col(column)
                       for rowid,cell1 in enumerate(col):
                           if cell1.value == "# Responses PCSAT YTD":#column value
                           print rowidx,colidx
                           print "Column Element Found"
                           print sheet.name
                           print (sheet.cell1(rowidx,colidx).value)#must be cell value
                           print "***************"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook("book.xlsx")
for sheet in book.sheets():
    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        for colidx,cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell.value == "PES":#row value
               print ("Found Row Element")
               print(rowidx, colidx)
```